# Diferenciar instância de classe de "instância" de interface

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface

Tem alguma maneira de diferenciar `v1` de `v2` no código abaixo, por `reflection` ou outro método?

```
var v1 = new MinhaClasse();
IMinhaClasse v2 = new MinhaClasse();
```

Quero executar um método somente se a `variável` for "instanciada" a partir da `Interface`, no exemplo acima somente seria possível chamar uma função se passasse como parâmetro `v2`

Outra maneira que solucionaria o problema seria evitar que um método tenha como parâmetro de entrada `IMinhaClasse` não aceite `MinhaClasse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como.

**`IMinhaClasse.cs`**

```
interface IMinhaClasse
{
    void IMinhaClasse();
}
```

**`MinhaClasse.cs`**

```
class MinhaClasse : IMinhaClasse
{

    public String campoMinhaClasse;

    public void metodoQueExisteSomenteMinhaClasse()
    {

    }

    public void IMinhaClasse()
    {

    }
}
```

**`Form1.cs`**

```
var v1 = new MinhaClasse();
IMinhaClasse v2 = new MinhaClasse();
```

**Campos: Teste v1**

```
v1.GetType().GetField("campoMinhaClasse") != null
```

= `true`, portanto, `v1` **tem** o campo `campoMinhaClasse`

**Campos: Teste v2**

```
v2.GetType().GetField("campoMinhaClasse") != null
```

= `true`, portanto, `v2` **tem** o campo `campoMinhaClasse`

**Métodos: Teste v1**

```
v1.GetType().GetMethod("metodoQueExisteSomenteMinhaClasse") != null
```

= `true`, portanto, `v1` **tem** o método `metodoQueExisteSomenteMinhaClasse`

**Métodos: Teste v2**

```
v2.GetType().GetMethod("metodoQueExisteSomenteMinhaClasse") != null
```

= `true`, portanto, `v2` **tem** o método `metodoQueExisteSomenteMinhaClasse`

**Conclusão**

Portanto, **NÃO** há como diferenciar estruturalmente a instância de `v1` de `v2`.

Comment: Testei as respostas mas não deram certo:
1 -  `if (v1 is IMinhaClasse)` e `if (v2 is MinhaClasse)` sempre são verdadeiros.

2 - método `.GetInterfaces()` não existe

3 - Sempre verdadeiro

Comment: É uma pergunta peculiar, já que para poder dizer que `IMinhaClasse v2 = new MinhaClasse()`, então `MinhaClasse` deve sempre implementar `IMinhaClasse`, então acredito ser impossível diferenciá-los da maneira que pretende

Comment: Realmente, porém, em `IMinhaClasse` por exemplo posso ter `atributos privados (somente com get)` já em `MinhaClasse` ter acesso completo `get; set;`. O motivo para isso é porque estou usando um ORM que exige  `MinhaClasse` tenha os métodos públicos e acessíveis `get; set;`. Por isso quero utilizar `IMinhaClasse` para "minimizar" este problema.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Mas por Reflection você consegue obter os atributos sim

Comment: Realmente, NÃO tem como. Vou alterar minha resposta com os testes.

Comment: Na sua conclusão você quis dizer que não há como diferenciar diretamente, somente comparando o conteúdo das classes é isso? Explique melhor a conclusão.

Comment: Opa, arrumei, havia escrito errado. Realmente não tem como diferenciar se é instancia de IMinhaClasse ou MinhaClasse...se fosse pra distinguir de qual(is) interfaces uma classe implementa, etc, dai seria simples...desta maneira, `var` é o mesmo que a classe base/interface que `MinhaClasse`.